# why stripe button is not appearing?

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I am integrating stripe checkout gateway in my website. For this , I am following a tutorial for this. I am copying its code as it is. However, the button is not displaying for me.

```
{% extends 'basic.html' %}

<h2> buy</h2>

<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-key="{{ key }}"
        data-description = "payment gateway"
        data-amount = "500"
        data-locale="auto">

</script>
```

I know that their is no button tag but the tutorial I am following is also the same .

I tried to implement a button which will take me to the checkout form.

Comment: Which tutorial are you following? This looks like an older way to implement Checkout. I recommend following this guide instead: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/quickstart

Comment: can you recommend me a django specific tutorial

Comment: I haven't tested either of these myself but these look like good places to start:
- https://testdriven.io/blog/django-stripe-tutorial/

- https://dev.to/documatic/integrate-stripe-payments-with-django-by-building-a-digital-products-selling-app-le5